# How in vue-resource read store setters value?

Tags: vuex, vue-resource

In my vue/cli 4/vuex / vue-resource project  I read data from protected area with passport from backend api as in routes/api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api',  'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
    ...
    Route::get('dashboard', 'API\Admin\DashboardController@index');
```

I found how to set access token at
[vue-resource interceptor for auth headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665244/vue-resource-interceptor-for-auth-headers)

and in src/main.js I added method :

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {   
/*
  console.log('request::')
  console.log(request)

  console.log('this::')
  console.log(this)

  console.log('Vue::')
  console.log(Vue)

  console.log('Vue.$store::')
  console.log(Vue.$store)

  console.log('Vue.$store.getters.token::')
  console.log(Vue.$store.getters.token)
*/

  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer XXX key')
  request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
  next()
})
```

and it works for me if I fill bearer token manually, but I did not find how to read it from store?
In my code above I failed to read $store.getters value...
Which is the valid way ?

**UPDATED BLOCK # 1:**
If in src/main.js I comment line :

```
import store from './store'
```

and add line :

```
import store from './store.js';
```

then in console I got error :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                           12:55:54 PM

This relative module was not found:

* ./store.js in ./src/main.js
```

But with

```
import store from './store'
```

I failed get access to store data

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing your Vuex file instead of trying to access the `$store` via the Vue instance.

```
import store from './store.js';

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {   
      request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${store.getters.token}`)
      request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      next()
})
```

Comment: Please, look UPDATED BLOCK # 1:

Comment: Did you add the token variable to your store.state (e.g. store.state.token)? Also, what does your folder structure and your Vuex file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found decision in writing token into localStorage on login and

```
reading this value from ue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => { 
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)
  request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
  next()
})
```

That works for me!